Is there a method to force text mode, without wrapping huge chunks of text inside \text{} or \mbox{}'s
In my latex source I wrap most of my maths text inside {} parameters passed to various formatting macros.
These can drop closing $ delimiters, or the latex parser sometimes inserts $'s when it thinks these are missing, causing normal text to be interpreted in math mode. Sometimes for many sections at a time (I split sections without a \par, I use \\ breaks - reasons below).
Is there a way to force text mode at the beginning of a section of text, whether it was left in math mode or not?
I don't want to wrap huge sections of text inside \text{} or \mbox{}  blocks, I want a single \ command something like
\def\ToText{ \SetMode{text} }

Here is a problem equation $ y = mx + c.
\ToText
And follow on text

I've tried gemini.google on this (my usual \quote{Phone a friend} - that's where the unusable suggestions to wrap in \text{} or \mbox{} arose.
It also hinted that \par would do the trick, however in {book} style I had to drop all \par in favour of // and // // (cannot sort out typing these with all the \ escape chars) as I didn't like the \par spacing or indenting (too much work to figure out how to change that, but now it seems it might be the better option!).

\par in favour of \\ and \\ \\ : this sounds very, very wrong. If you would like to separate paragraphs with vertical space, have a look at the parskip package.

It works for me, too late to change now - doc is due soon

split sections without a \par, I use \\ breaks - reasons below that is never right you are setting all the text as a single paragraph.

Your question is very unclear and you have only posted fragments of code but Here is a problem equation $ y = mx + c.   is a clear syntax error with an unmatched $ starting math mode that is not closed. You can not expect any system to cope with arbitrary syntax errors  what do you want ti happen here?

I have a feeling you are looking for \def\ToText{\ifmmode$\fi}  which ends math mode if it is used in math but there are absolutely no cases where this would be a good markup to use.

Thanks David, that \ifmmode  which adds a closing $ is exactly what I was after.
The document formatting structure is locked in now, way too late to think about changing it.  The output it produces is fine for me, even if a single para

The document markup is so wrong, I would strongly urge that you do not use it for anything. Even if it takes you a couple of days or weeks to clean up the input syntax. Using a document marked up in this way and just hiding syntax errors with more obscure macros making  incorrect output that does not flag errors is not useful in the end.

Why can't you just spend 5 minutes in your editor replacing every \toText by $ with a mode that you say yes or no to the replacement, so that adds all the missing $ then just remove the remaining \toText that do nothing.

The document
\documentclass{article}
\def\ToText{\ifmmode$\fi}

\begin{document}

Here is a problem equation $ y = mx + c.
\ToText
And follow on text


Here is a problem equation $ y = mx + c$.
\ToText
And follow on text
\end{document}

Gives no error as the \ToText command inserts a $ to end math if used in math, and does nothing otherwise.
However the resulting document is incorrect as in the first case the math ended too late, the . is part of the sentence structure and should be in text not as part of the math. This may or may not be visible in the output (even if you re-insert a space by using \toText{} And) depending on the fonts used, and whether \frenchspacing is used, but even if the error is not visible, it is still an error and will affect tagging and accessibility.
You write

These can drop closing $ delimiters, or the latex parser sometimes inserts $'s when it thinks these are missing,

But the latex parser never makes subjective judgements, it will insert $ if there are syntax errors in the input.
To mark the end of a paragraph always use a blank line, not \par (which is the same as a blank line but less readable in the source) and certainly not \\  which does not end the paragraph.

Using "\ifmmode $" is perfect for my current urgent need , thank you very much :-D

@AlexirHannah No matter how urgent, This should not be used. Fixing your document to add the missing $ will take less time than it took you to post the question here.

I flush out the problems in parallel, it's often something stupid like using a \sigma in running text, or a \quad or , for spacing - generally the latex parser inserts the problem $'s.
I'd like to proof read the text as much as possible while sorting out eqn typesetting too.  Havingwholesentencesmangledbytheparsersdecisionsmakesmylifedifficult!

TeX makes absolutely no attempt to make reasonable output after an error. Don't even look at the pdf output, so the fact that the spaces are gone should not trouble you. you should simply fix the error in the source. Patching latex to make incorrect input kind of half work makes no sense at all, it will make your document much harder to debug as errors are not flagged. @AlexirHannah

Havingwholesentencesmangledbytheparser totally mischaracterizes what is happening here. The parser hasn't mangled anything, the output is a direct result of incorrect input, so you should fix the input. don't blame the parser for flagging input errors. @AlexirHannah
